# Phonegap Consuming Web Service PHP

Tags: php, web-services, cordova, phonegap-build

The next problem is try to consume a web service. I try with plugins and pure xml but the result still be "NULL".

The code is this.

```
function soap(imei,clave)
    {

    var divToBeWorkedOn = "#res";
    var webServiceURL = '';

    var parameters = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> \
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=" http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance " xmlns:xsd=" http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema " xmlns:soap=" http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"> \
      <soap:Body> \
        <registra_imei> \
          <request> \
            <imei>'+imei+'</imei> \
            <clave>'+clave+'</clave> \
          </request> \
        </registra_imei> \
      </soap:Body> \
    </soap:Envelope>';

    $.ajax({
        type: "Post",
        url: webServiceURL,
        data: parameters,
        contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(msg) {    
            alert("funciono "+msg);
        },
        error: function(e){
            alert("error");              
        }
    });
}
```

The Web services is a simple SOAP PHP. Just I need send the variables and then get a response that will be a code (1, 2 or 3).

The requeriment from the event "registra_imei" are this:

```
Name: registra_imei
Binding: SOAPBinding
Endpoint: 
SoapAction: urn:soapwsdl#registra_imei
Style: rpc
Input:
  use: encoded
  namespace: urn:soapwsdl
  encodingStyle: http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/
  message: registra_imeiRequest
  parts:
    imei: xsd:string
    clave: xsd:string
Output:
  use: encoded
  namespace: urn:soapwsdl
  encodingStyle: http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/
  message: registra_imeiResponse
  parts:
    return: xsd:int
Namespace: urn:soapwsdl
Transport: http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http
Documentation: Registra imei
```

Comment: What is the question? Are you getting errors?

Comment: Some XML tags is incorrect? The Comsume from Phonegap App exist but the message from response send a NULL. Another alternative is the SOAP Web Service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My comment is too long to post it into the comment area.

So, using `SoapUI` i simulated a call to your `WSDL` and i got this as a `RAW` response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 14 Apr 2015 19:44:24 GMT
Server: LiteSpeed
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.39
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=870fgce5tm1ep8get75066i491; path=/
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 0
```

This is the `SOAP` request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:soapwsdl">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:registra_imei soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
         <imei xsi:type="xsd:string">65656565</imei>
         <clave xsi:type="xsd:string">123</clave>
      </urn:registra_imei>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

`RAW` request:

```
POST http://soap.movilaccesscloud.cl/serversoap.php/ HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
SOAPAction: "urn:soapwsdl#registra_imei"
Content-Length: 508
Host: soap.movilaccesscloud.cl
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)
```

Apparently, the error is in the back-end of your webservice. Check your PHP code, if possible please share part of the code.

I repeat, my intention was to put the comment in the proper area, but as you can see it´s too long.

:)

Comment: Thanks! Was problem from the Web Server.